# Beego commentsRouter

Tags: api, go, beego

I'm new at Beego framework. I have experience at Laravel PHP framework and I think Beego is a little bit different I guess. How these `commentsRouter` generated and what is this for? Is this automatically generates or just have to add by my hand and define route methods?

Comment: I believe `commentsRouter` is just an example router, you're in charge of writing the code for any router. See minimum example here: https://beego.me/docs/quickstart/router.md

Answer (score 2):

Yes, commentsRouter_controller.go is generate automatically. Example:
In controller User.go

// @router /get-admin-user [get]
func (c *UserController) GetAdminUser() {}

In commentsRouter_controller.go will be generate again and add route

beego.GlobalControllerRouter["app/controllers:UserController"] = append(beego.GlobalControllerRouter["app/controllers:UserController"],
        beego.ControllerComments{
            Method: "GetAdminUser",
            Router: `/get-admin-user`,
            AllowHTTPMethods: []string{"get"},
            MethodParams: param.Make(),
            Filters: nil,
            Params: nil})

Answer (score 1):

If you use `bee api ...` to create an API project, you will get these default files:

```
controllers
├── object.go
└── user.go
models
├── object.go
└── user.go
routers
├── commentsRouter_controllers.go
└── router.go
```

They are samples that help you to write your own logic.